# Timer in another timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

is it possible to create timer inside timer in javascript?
I tried, but it didnt work - it did the inner timer only once.
Anyone can help me?Thank you!

```
var tid3 = setTimeout(timer2, 0);   

    function timer2() {

                var t = 0;


                var tid2 = setTimeout(timerImg, 0);

                function timerImg() {
                    alert(t);                    
                    t++;
                    tid2 = setTimeout(1000);
                }


        tid3 = setTimeout(1000);
    }
```

Comment: It is supposed to do the inner timer only once, that is what Timeout does. Try setInterval for multiple invocations...

Comment: can u elaborate a little. I'm pretty new to js. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have timer2() invoked multiple times every x seconds?

Comment: should explain what your goal is since your code is invalid

Comment: Every second (the first timer) should load a html page if some condition is met.
In the second timer, every second, i want to change something in the html page that is loaded.

Comment: Read the following in depth:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp   You will find that setTimeout always takes a minimum of two parameters.  One being the duration of the timer and the other a function to call when the timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (from your example) that you are trying to get the function to execute immediately and then run periodically. I've marked the lines that you need to remove if you don't want them to run immediately.

```
function timer2() {

   var t = 0;

   function timerImg() {
       alert(t);                    
       t++;
   }

   timerImg(); // Remove to not run immediately
   setInterval(timerImg, 1000);
}

timer2(); // Remove to not run immediately
setInterval(timer2, 1000);
```